# Android: How to set CheckBox text gravity to center of entire control?

Tags: android, xml, styles

I'm gonna explain this with a picture:

[image: 1]

Okey. This is how a CheckBox works when I set gravity to 'center'. But, I want to put it in the center of the entire object, taking the red area as reference.

[image: 2]

How can I do it?
Maybe using `android:paddingLeft=-30dp`, but I think there is a better way.

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> if You fix the Width

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="My Check Box"
    android:gravity="center"

    />
```

[image]

> With Wrap Parent and padding...

```
  <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="My Check Box"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"

    />
```

[image]

> By relative layout and TextView

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
  >

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@null"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"

    android:gravity="center"></CheckBox>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="My Check Box"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: wrap content and centralize component. Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use textAligment property

```
checkbox.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
```

Comment: this most probably won't work - at least it does not for `Chip`s, which inherits from CheckBox

Answer (score 0):

I don't think checkbox has such a property, here is an alternate solution to achieve this kind of requirement:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text=""

                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="MyCheckBox"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and how about this?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"></CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```